# Find and replace using a df as a replacement

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
    1                   2
0   GB_GCA_002084765.1  p__4572-55
1   GB_GCA_002127415.1  p__AABM5-125-24
2   GB_GCA_002325765.1  p__AB1-6
3   GB_GCA_002686915.1  p__ARS69
4   GB_GCA_003223295.1  p__Acidobacteriota
... ... ...
122 GB_GCA_002049785.1  p__WOR-3
123 GB_GCA_002421425.1  p__WOR-3_A
124 GB_GCA_002774315.1  p__WOR-3_B
125 GB_GCA_001791795.1  p__Wallbacteria
126 GB_GCA_003520965.1  p__Zixibacteria
```

And I have an ete3 document that basically can be represented as a long string.

```
'((((((((((((((((((((((GB_GCA_002084765.1:0.00066,RS_GCF_001730225.1:0.11732)21.0:0.0294,RS_GCF_003144315.1:0.17656)40.0:0.12931,GB_GCA_002427055.1:0.33253)20.0:0.02904,(GB_GCA_001513495.1:0.30605,GB_GCA_002375925.1:0.29292)15.0:0.02728)1.0:0.02137,(GB_GCA_000508525.1:0.01172,GB_GCA_003445555.1:0.02571)52.0:0.02627)5.0:0.02987,RS_GCF_000703065.1:0.08152)8.0:0.03285,RS_GCF_900167185.1:0.11652)14.0:0.03175,GB_GCA_002313635.1:0.76132)18.0:0.04762,(RS_GCF_002026065.1:0.00234,GB_GCA_002774365.1:0.24464)85.0:0.05372)11.0:0.03236,((((GB_GCA_900313515.1:0.14273,GB_GCA_002898935.1:0.31806)68.0:0.04478,(GB_GCA_002410925.1:0.5357,GB_GCA_002343445.1:0.2918)49.0:0.03026)51.0:0.03853,GB_GCA_001768645.1:0.43025)3.0:0.02989,(((GB_GCA_001567485.1:0.29325,(GB_GCA_001917775.1:0.10303,GB_GCA_001795345.1:0.19096)67.0:0.03758)96.0:0.06762,GB_GCA_003545515.1:0.20297)74.0:0.04873,((GB_GCA_002050035.1:0.90203,GB_GCA_002435745.1:0.69392)61.0:0.12728,RS_GCF_000381045.1:0.01504)13.0:0.07804)10.0:0.0353)14.0:0.0454)3.0:0.02404,(((RS_GCF_000023325.1:0.16963,GB_GCA_001778455.1:0.44503)73.0:0.06823,((GB_GCA_003140815.1:0.02053,RS_GCF_000378005.1:0.14545)54.0:0.07617,(GB_GCA_002878375.1:0.18447,RS_GCF_003057965.1:0.04345)13.0:0.06069)53.0:0.05862)30.0:0.03852,(RS_GCF_000025885.1:0.09029,GB_GCA_003542295.1:0.34122)88.0:0.04389)34.0:0.05388)2.0:0.0233,(((GB_GCA_002869225.1:0.62755,GB_GCA_002422125.1:0.35473)88.0:0.08651,GB_GCA_900317935.1:0.1949)86.0:0.07019,GB_GCA_001791795.1:0.07755)63.0:0.09509)4.0:0.02337,(((GB_GCA_002364975.1:0.02785,GB_GCA_002329605.1:0.55882)21.0:0.03064,RS_GCF_002727185.1:0.0104)76.0:0.06471,(GB_GCA_001604275.1:0.13526,GB_GCA_002501535.1:0.0392)4.0:0.04756)1.0:0.03479)0.0:0.01704,(((((((((GB_GCA_001304035.1:0.54018,GB_GCA_002084535.1:0.18606)95.0:0.04306,GB_GCA_002049825.1:0.38318)86.0:0.03923,RS_GCF_900115205.1:0.10695)83.0:0.03155,GB_GCA_002710515.1:0.04282)53.0:0.02837,(GB_GCA_003477045.1:0.13797,GB_GCA_002127415.1:0.50499)92.0:0.07587)98.0:0.06011,(RS_GCF_900167415.1:0.06002,GB_GCA_001577135.1:0.38714)23.0:0.03821)20.0:0.03262,(((((GB_GCA_002085285.1:0.23535,GB_GCA_003235575.1:0.42955)46.0:0.04256,(GB_GCA_002686915.1:0.50419,GB_GCA_002686955.1:0.59477)53.0:0.08394)54.0:0.03609,GB_GCA_001780825.1:0.52756)72.0:0.0565,((GB_GCA_001303705.1:0.46156,GB_GCA_001777915.1:0.19796)57.0:0.07801,(GB_GCA_001304015.1:0.43757,GB_GCA_002084765.1:0.55015)18.0:0.03967)60.0:0.03821)41.0:0.0323,((GB_GCA_003520965.1:0.13291,GB_GCA_002085385.1:0.55716)74.0:0.0402,GB_GCA_002724215.1:0.18913)26.0:0.03354)25.0:0.03193)27.0:0.04116,((((GB_GCA_002421425.1:0.11551,GB_GCA_000494225.1:0.2046)16.0:0.08044,GB_GCA_002049785.1:0.21005)3.0:0.04452,GB_GCA_002774315.1:0.11867)5.0:0.06943,GB_GCA_002414865.1:0.23715)0.0:0.04977)2.0:0.03934,((((GB_GCA_001567115.1:0.72461,GB_GCA_000493945.1:0.42109)56.0:0.06264,GB_GCA_002699335.1:0.11654)53.0:0.04013,GB_GCA_001774505.1:0.86947)26.0:0.02743,GB_GCA_003290465.1:0.22786)12.0:0.03059)0.0:0.01961)0.0:0.01729,((((((((GB_GCA_000989955.1:0.29733,GB_GCA_002325765.1:1.19673)5.0:0.13318,GB_GCA_002309575.1:0.16417)2.0:0.08148,GB_GCA_002707655.1:0.03468)0.0:0.05111,GB_GCA_002708205.1:0.25497)1.0:0.0422,((((RS_GCF_001547735.1:0.51823,GB_GCA_002341805.1:0.14728)32.0:0.04993,RS_GCF_002119425.1:0.09391)33.0:0.05139,(RS_GCF_000025725.1:0.06683,RS_GCF_000469585.1:0.24443)81.0:0.08857)20.0:0.03554,(GB_GCA_003232385.1:0.76335,GB_GCA_002898375.1:0.1541)28.0:0.05736)8.0:0.03489)0.0:0.02535,((((((RS_GCF_900111775.1:0.01384,GB_GCA_001798165.1:0.09561)85.0:0.05314,RS_GCF_001548275.1:0.15293)1.0:0.01916,((((GB_GCA_001873285.1:0.47088,GB_GCA_002083365.1:0.0416)49.0:0.03707,((GB_GCA_000739515.1:0.15172,GB_GCA_003230635.1:0.32654)69.0:0.0513,GB_GCA_001643535.1:0.1041)75.0:0.03387)33.0:0.02654,(((GB_GCA_002238965.1:0.20865,RS_GCF_900079095.1:0.02428)57.0:0.07091,GB_GCA_001803565.1:0.41221)59.0:0.03192,GB_GCA_001790645.1:0.00229)41.0:0.02974)46.0:0.0331,GB_GCA_002897695.1:0.1924)28.0:0.02889)1.0:0.02667,(((GB_GCA_002238415.1:0.42142,GB_GCA_002869005.1:0.03069)27.0:0.03507,(GB_GCA_003170555.1:0.555,GB_GCA_002279275.1:0.02905)4.0:0.06422)1.0:0.02775,GB_GCA_001797815.1:0.47619)12.0:0.02571)1.0:0.02825,((((GB_GCA_001799195.1:0.71958,GB_GCA_002725955.1:0.31002)8.0_p__Bdellovibrionota_B:0.0302,GB_GCA_002709835.1:0.08741)7.0:0.03426,(GB_GCA_002342225.1:0.64848,GB_GCA_001798265.1:0.49397)60.0:0.06653)21.0:0.02546,GB_GCA_002796305.1:0.36002)28.0:0.03508)0.0:0.02277,GB_GCA_001311565.1:0.34049)20.0:0.0245)0.0:0.01634,GB_GCA_002347965.1:0.78624)2.0:0.02141,GB_GCA_003223295.1:0.03279)1.0:0.04518)1.0:0.02801,GB_GCA_002780065.1:0.7374)9.0:0.03269,(GB_GCA_001730085.1:0.7896,GB_GCA_001804225.1:0.2151)49.0:0.06761)6.0:0.02498,((GB_GCA_003167475.1:0.15987,GB_GCA_001778355.1:0.04582)73.0:0.08013,(GB_GCA_002428325.1:0.58652,GB_GCA_003152075.1:0.13284)15.0:0.06451)16.0:0.04593)5.0:0.02319,(GB_GCA_002478245.1:0.43503,GB_GCA_003485015.1:0.47277)36.0:0.06091)3.0:0.02965,(GB_GCA_001871075.1:0.33481,GB_GCA_000402295.1:0.62651)28.0:0.06283)42.0:0.04784,((GB_GCA_900321865.1:0.78483,GB_GCA_003153935.1:0.14501)31.0:0.0668,GB_GCA_002311025.1:0.27636)47.0:0.056)100.0:0.35313,GB_GCA_002779055.1:0.28413);'
```

I want to replace each value of column 1 for the equivalent value on column 2.

For example, the first value in the string (**GB_GCA_002084765.1**) must be replaced for the value that is in same row, column 2:  **p__4572-55**

```
'((((((((((((((((((((((p__4572-55:0.00066,RS_GCF_001730225.1:0.11732)21.0:0.0294,RS_GCF_003144315.1:0.17656)40.0:0.12931,GB_GCA_002427055.1:0.33253)20.0:0.02904,(GB_GCA_001513495.1:0.30605,GB_GCA_002375925.1:0.29292)15.0:0.02728)1.0:0.02137,(GB_GCA_000508525.1:0.01172,GB_GCA_003445555.1:0.02571)52.0:0.02627)5.0:0.02987,RS_GCF_000703065.1:0.08152)8.0:0.03285,RS_GCF_900167185.1:0.11652)14.0:0.03175,GB_GCA_002313635.1:0.76132)18.0:0.04762,(RS_GCF_002026065.1:0.00234,GB_GCA_002774365.1:0.24464)85.0:0.05372)11.0:0.03236,((((GB_GCA_900313515.1:0.14273,GB_GCA_002898935.1:0.31806)68.0:0.04478,(GB_GCA_002410925.1:0.5357,GB_GCA_002343445.1:0.2918)49.0:0.03026)51.0:0.03853,GB_GCA_001768645.1:0.43025)3.0:0.02989,(((GB_GCA_001567485.1:0.29325,(GB_GCA_001917775.1:0.10303,GB_GCA_001795345.1:0.19096)67.0:0.03758)96.0:0.06762,GB_GCA_003545515.1:0.20297)74.0:0.04873,((GB_GCA_002050035.1:0.90203,GB_GCA_002435745.1:0.69392)61.0:0.12728,RS_GCF_000381045.1:0.01504)13.0:0.07804)10.0:0.0353)14.0:0.0454)3.0:0.02404,(((RS_GCF_000023325.1:0.16963,GB_GCA_001778455.1:0.44503)73.0:0.06823,((GB_GCA_003140815.1:0.02053,RS_GCF_000378005.1:0.14545)54.0:0.07617,(GB_GCA_002878375.1:0.18447,RS_GCF_003057965.1:0.04345)13.0:0.06069)53.0:0.05862)30.0:0.03852,(RS_GCF_000025885.1:0.09029,GB_GCA_003542295.1:0.34122)88.0:0.04389)34.0:0.05388)2.0:0.0233,(((GB_GCA_002869225.1:0.62755,GB_GCA_002422125.1:0.35473)88.0:0.08651,GB_GCA_900317935.1:0.1949)86.0:0.07019,GB_GCA_001791795.1:0.07755)63.0:0.09509)4.0:0.02337,(((GB_GCA_002364975.1:0.02785,GB_GCA_002329605.1:0.55882)21.0:0.03064,RS_GCF_002727185.1:0.0104)76.0:0.06471,(GB_GCA_001604275.1:0.13526,GB_GCA_002501535.1:0.0392)4.0:0.04756)1.0:0.03479)0.0:0.01704,(((((((((GB_GCA_001304035.1:0.54018,GB_GCA_002084535.1:0.18606)95.0:0.04306,GB_GCA_002049825.1:0.38318)86.0:0.03923,RS_GCF_900115205.1:0.10695)83.0:0.03155,GB_GCA_002710515.1:0.04282)53.0:0.02837,(GB_GCA_003477045.1:0.13797,GB_GCA_002127415.1:0.50499)92.0:0.07587)98.0:0.06011,(RS_GCF_900167415.1:0.06002,GB_GCA_001577135.1:0.38714)23.0:0.03821)20.0:0.03262,(((((GB_GCA_002085285.1:0.23535,GB_GCA_003235575.1:0.42955)46.0:0.04256,(GB_GCA_002686915.1:0.50419,GB_GCA_002686955.1:0.59477)53.0:0.08394)54.0:0.03609,GB_GCA_001780825.1:0.52756)72.0:0.0565,((GB_GCA_001303705.1:0.46156,GB_GCA_001777915.1:0.19796)57.0:0.07801,(GB_GCA_001304015.1:0.43757,GB_GCA_002084765.1:0.55015)18.0:0.03967)60.0:0.03821)41.0:0.0323,((GB_GCA_003520965.1:0.13291,GB_GCA_002085385.1:0.55716)74.0:0.0402,GB_GCA_002724215.1:0.18913)26.0:0.03354)25.0:0.03193)27.0:0.04116,((((GB_GCA_002421425.1:0.11551,GB_GCA_000494225.1:0.2046)16.0:0.08044,GB_GCA_002049785.1:0.21005)3.0:0.04452,GB_GCA_002774315.1:0.11867)5.0:0.06943,GB_GCA_002414865.1:0.23715)0.0:0.04977)2.0:0.03934,((((GB_GCA_001567115.1:0.72461,GB_GCA_000493945.1:0.42109)56.0:0.06264,GB_GCA_002699335.1:0.11654)53.0:0.04013,GB_GCA_001774505.1:0.86947)26.0:0.02743,GB_GCA_003290465.1:0.22786)12.0:0.03059)0.0:0.01961)0.0:0.01729,((((((((GB_GCA_000989955.1:0.29733,GB_GCA_002325765.1:1.19673)5.0:0.13318,GB_GCA_002309575.1:0.16417)2.0:0.08148,GB_GCA_002707655.1:0.03468)0.0:0.05111,GB_GCA_002708205.1:0.25497)1.0:0.0422,((((RS_GCF_001547735.1:0.51823,GB_GCA_002341805.1:0.14728)32.0:0.04993,RS_GCF_002119425.1:0.09391)33.0:0.05139,(RS_GCF_000025725.1:0.06683,RS_GCF_000469585.1:0.24443)81.0:0.08857)20.0:0.03554,(GB_GCA_003232385.1:0.76335,GB_GCA_002898375.1:0.1541)28.0:0.05736)8.0:0.03489)0.0:0.02535,((((((RS_GCF_900111775.1:0.01384,GB_GCA_001798165.1:0.09561)85.0:0.05314,RS_GCF_001548275.1:0.15293)1.0:0.01916,((((GB_GCA_001873285.1:0.47088,GB_GCA_002083365.1:0.0416)49.0:0.03707,((GB_GCA_000739515.1:0.15172,GB_GCA_003230635.1:0.32654)69.0:0.0513,GB_GCA_001643535.1:0.1041)75.0:0.03387)33.0:0.02654,(((GB_GCA_002238965.1:0.20865,RS_GCF_900079095.1:0.02428)57.0:0.07091,GB_GCA_001803565.1:0.41221)59.0:0.03192,GB_GCA_001790645.1:0.00229)41.0:0.02974)46.0:0.0331,GB_GCA_002897695.1:0.1924)28.0:0.02889)1.0:0.02667,(((GB_GCA_002238415.1:0.42142,GB_GCA_002869005.1:0.03069)27.0:0.03507,(GB_GCA_003170555.1:0.555,GB_GCA_002279275.1:0.02905)4.0:0.06422)1.0:0.02775,GB_GCA_001797815.1:0.47619)12.0:0.02571)1.0:0.02825,((((GB_GCA_001799195.1:0.71958,GB_GCA_002725955.1:0.31002)8.0_p__Bdellovibrionota_B:0.0302,GB_GCA_002709835.1:0.08741)7.0:0.03426,(GB_GCA_002342225.1:0.64848,GB_GCA_001798265.1:0.49397)60.0:0.06653)21.0:0.02546,GB_GCA_002796305.1:0.36002)28.0:0.03508)0.0:0.02277,GB_GCA_001311565.1:0.34049)20.0:0.0245)0.0:0.01634,GB_GCA_002347965.1:0.78624)2.0:0.02141,GB_GCA_003223295.1:0.03279)1.0:0.04518)1.0:0.02801,GB_GCA_002780065.1:0.7374)9.0:0.03269,(GB_GCA_001730085.1:0.7896,GB_GCA_001804225.1:0.2151)49.0:0.06761)6.0:0.02498,((GB_GCA_003167475.1:0.15987,GB_GCA_001778355.1:0.04582)73.0:0.08013,(GB_GCA_002428325.1:0.58652,GB_GCA_003152075.1:0.13284)15.0:0.06451)16.0:0.04593)5.0:0.02319,(GB_GCA_002478245.1:0.43503,GB_GCA_003485015.1:0.47277)36.0:0.06091)3.0:0.02965,(GB_GCA_001871075.1:0.33481,GB_GCA_000402295.1:0.62651)28.0:0.06283)42.0:0.04784,((GB_GCA_900321865.1:0.78483,GB_GCA_003153935.1:0.14501)31.0:0.0668,GB_GCA_002311025.1:0.27636)47.0:0.056)100.0:0.35313,GB_GCA_002779055.1:0.28413);'
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dict or list from the Pandas dataframe, iterate over the entries and replace the strings. Something like:

```
d = df.to_dict('record')
for row in d:
    ete3_string.replace(row['1'], row['2'])
```